# How to set x button for delete records on database on every row using listview-xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have listview to which I add the names of cities. I have a field to enter ID and a button to delete the name. Is there an option to place an X button on each line against each added name to delete the name without manually adding ID and pressing a button ?

My xaml code:

```
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="SQLite" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtPersonId" Placeholder="PersonId Update and Delete"></Entry>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" WidthRequest="200" Text="Delete" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lstPersons">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding PersonID}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

My xaml.cs look like:

```
 private async void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
        {
            //Get Person
            var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));
            if (person != null)
            {
                //Delete Person
                await App.SQLiteDb.DeleteItemAsync(person);
                txtPersonId.Text = string.Empty;
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Deleted", "OK");

                //Get All Persons
                var personList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
                if (personList != null)
                {
                    lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter PersonID", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: use a ViewCell instead of a TextCell and add whatever UI you need in the ViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set x button for delete records on database on every row using listview-xamarin

You can take a look [custom cell in ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells) firstly, then take a look the following code:

```
   <ListView x:Name="lstPersons">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding PersonID}" />
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Button
                                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                Text="Delete a record" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Then you can delete current ListView row by Button.click, loading ListView data again.

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var person = btn.BindingContext as personclass;
        //delete this item.
        //......
    }
```